# Define a variable and run as command in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to define a line of batch command and run it

I use something like this :

```
pushd "%WORKSPACE%"
set mycommand = translate.py documentname
%XD%
```

but it doesn't run at all

Anybody knows how to do it ?

Comment: You should not have any spaces between your variable and `=` since this will create an environment variable called "mycommand " *notice* the trailing space

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be like:

```
 pushd "%WORKSPACE"
 set mycommand=translate.py "documentname.py"
 %mycommand%
```

Hopefully it's like that...